# Create folders outside my root folder in server. PHP

Tags: php

So I have a php file name NewUser.php inside a folder called "UserActions".

"UserActions" is inside a folder call "General Elements"
NewUser.php inserts in a database the user data, now here is my problem I need that the user image when is uploaded is saved on the folder User Images, which is outside the root file of its php.

Im using mkdir() but I dont know how to acces the folder UserImages.

```
0. General Elements
  0.0 UserActions     
     0.0.0 NewUser.php  //MkDir() function
  0.1 UserImages        //I need to create a folder here and save here the images.
      0.1.0 User_0
         0.1.0.0 MainImage.jpg
         0.1.0.1 MainBackground.jpg
      0.1 User_1
         0.1.1.0 MainImage.jpg
         0.1.1.1 MainBackground.jpg
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that the folder your .php is in isn't the actual server root and just a folder. You can simply use `..` in your path to go up one level. For example: If I am trying to access the Userimages folder from NewUser.php, I would use `../Userimages/`

Comment: Thanks alot. Works nice.